# ¿Cómo recorrer un array dentro de un objeto dentro de un array?

Tags: javascript, array, objeto

¿Cómo recorro un array (`mensajes`) dentro de un objeto dentro de un array?

```js
var array = []
array.push({mensajes: ["hola","stack"]})
document.write(JSON.stringify(array))
```

Answer (score 1):

El contenido de la varible `array` es:

```
var array = [{mensajes : ["hola", "stack"]}];
```

Para acceder al primer elemento del array se usa el índice 0:

```
var primerElemento = array[0];
// {mensajes : ["hola", "stack"]}
```

Para acceder a la propiedad mensajes se usa la notación `obj.propiedad`:

```
var arreglo = array[0].mensajes;
// ["hola", "stack"]
```

Para recorrer el arreglo una alternativa es utilizar la sentencia `for...of`, la cual crea un bucle que itera a través de los elementos de objetos iterables (como un array).

```
var array = [];
array.push({
    mensajes: ["hola","stack"]
});

for (let variable of array[0].mensajes) {
    console.log(variable);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Asumiendo que siempre mantendrás esa estructura puedes recorrer el arreglo inicial y luego, dentro de éste, recorrer la propiedad **`mensajes`**.

A partir de ahí, ya depende de cómo deseas procesar o mostrar el contenido de la propiedad `mensajes`.

Te dejo el código usando el método [**`forEach`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach) nativo de los arreglos en JavaScript (o también en [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wardo/xocadqpa/3/)).

```js
var array = []
array.push({
  mensajes: ["hola", "stack"]
})

var mensajes = []; //arreglo que tendrá los mensajes recorridos

array.forEach((item) => { //Recorro primer arreglo
  //Luego recorro la propiedad mensajes dentro del arreglo
  item.mensajes.forEach((mensaje) => {
    // Obtengo cada mensaje de la propiedad y la guardo en mi arreglo de mensajes
    mensajes.push(mensaje);
  });
});

// Imprimo todos los mensajes en el html
var mensajesDom = document.getElementById('mensajes');
mensajesDom.innerHTML = mensajes;
```

```html
<pre id="mensajes">
  
</pre>
```

Comment: Hola @EduardoPeredo. Bienvenido a [es.so] y gracias por tu aporte. Agregué el ejemplo de código en el cuerpo de tu respuesta. En estos casos, queda más práctico así, y se espera ver la solución dentro de la respuesta (no en un enlace externo -que puede agregarse para complementar, pero no para responder). Si vas a agregar código JavaScript/HTML/CSS, fijate el botón "`< >`" dentro del editor al momento de responder, que funciona igual que jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Sabes que en la posición `0` de `array` tienes un objeto y que en ese objeto tienes una propiedad que es del tipo array.

Puedes acceder a las propiedades del objeto mediante la notación `objeto.propiedad` o `objeto[propiedad]`.

Ver: [MDN - Trabajando con objetos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Trabajando_con_objectos)

Entonces, mediante `array[0]["mensajes"]` o `array[0].mensajes` puedes acceder a la propiedad `mensajes` del objeto que se encuentra en la posición 0 de `array`. Esa propiedad es a su vez del tipo array por lo que puedes iterar sobre sus elementos:

```js
var array = [];
array.push({
mensajes: ["hola","stack"]
});

for(var i=0; i< array[0].mensajes.length; i++){
   console.log(array[0].mensajes[i]);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que el array principal no tendrá un único elemento, puedo recorrer el array, y a cada elemento de ese array, que son objetos, recorrer la propiedad `"mensajes"`, que es un array.

Hay muchas maneras de hacerlo, puede ser con un `for`, `while`, y demás. En mi solución, hago uso de `map`, `=>` (funciones flecha), los condicionales de una sola línea (`si ? esto : sino`), y las funciones recursivas.

El procedimiento es el siguiente:

1. Hago un array con varios elementos `{"mensajes":["hola","stack"]}`.
2. Llamo a la función `recorrer`.

Esta función recibe dos parámetros, uno es el array, y el otro es la propiedad, que en este caso es `"mensajes"`.

- Si existe el segundo argumento, se llama recursivamente a sí mismo (`recorrer`), con el array `"mensajes"`, sin el segundo argumento.
- De lo contrario, recorre el array normalmente mediante `map` y las funciones flecha y escribe en el *HTML* cada elemento.

```js
function recorrer(array,propiedad)
{
  array.map(
    propiedad ? elemento => recorrer(elemento[propiedad])
    : elemento => document.write("<div>"+elemento+"</div>")
  )
}

var array = []
for(var i=0;i<2;i++)
{
  array.push( {"mensajes":["hola","stack"]} )
}

recorrer(array,"mensajes")
```